# CSS Calc((100%/5)+10px) isn't working

Tags: css, css-calc

Alright so in my CSS I'm trying to do the math calc((100%/5)+10px); When I do this It doesn't work. When I do calc(100%/5); It works just fine. What do I need to do to get the +10px working?

Comment: Try taking the px outside of the calculation? `calc((100%/5)+10)px` ?

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do, is use the proper syntax:

```
calc((100%/5) + 10px)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc: *“Note: The `+` and `-` operators must always be surrounded by whitespace.”*